# Need to convert Visual Basic code to Java using automated tools

Tags: java, source-code

I would like to convert VBA macros from Excel to Java code. The code conversion need not comply to Object Oriented methodology. I tried to find something on google and found the following 2 links

1. [Sun Offers VB to Java Conversion Tool](http://windowsitpro.com/windows-server/sun-offer-visual-basic-java-conversion-tool) : Did Sun actually develop such a tool? If yes, where can I find this?
2. [Online Code Convertor](https://varycode.com/) : This tool converts the code other way from Java to VB. I would like to know if there is such a tool for Java to VB and the tool need not be an online tool.

Any help on this is appreciated.

Also note that the code in VB represents a computational engine which needs to be used in an application developed in java and calling the executable VB code is not an option.

Comment: There are some [VB6 to Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426225/vb6-to-java-converter) translators, but I don't know if they are compatible with VBA.